# Pandas Dataframe rename duplicate values in Row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
COL1   COL2   COL3
 Red    Blue   Green
 Red    Yellow  Blue
 Blue   Red     Blue
```

I want to rename value in the dataframe if they appear 2x (or more) in a row

So the expected output is

```
COL1   COL2   COL3
 Red    Blue   Green
 Red    Yellow  Blue
 Blue   Red     2Blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a custom function here which will check if values are [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) in a row and add an [`incremental counter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to each of them after using [`series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
def myf(x):
    counter = x.groupby(x).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
    return x.mask(x.duplicated(),x.radd(counter))
```

---

```
print(df.apply(myf,axis=1))
#or df.T.apply(myf).T

   COL1    COL2   COL3
0   Red    Blue  Green
1   Red  Yellow   Blue
2  Blue     Red  2Blue
```

Comment: COL1[0] & COL1[1] are both Red, though

Comment: how can I do this on select columns. I.e. if column if the index is greater than 0. So far I have (I've removed the counter for the time being to keep the example simple

Comment: df.loc[df.index>0,df.mask(df.duplicated(),df.radd('2'))]

Comment: @fred.schwartz `df.duplicated()` will return the entre df  here since it will check for all columns together you can also select columns `df['col_A','col_B']].apply()` when doing this